# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "+i+"

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, freemarker

I am trying to access the value an array of data[].name in jsp. When I enter console.log('${data[0].name}') in javascript inside a jsp file it works. When I use a loop

> for(int i=0;i<=count;i++){ console.log('${data['+i+'].name}'

Getting java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "+i+"

Comment: Problem is, the for loop runs later than the template. So the template sees `date['+i+']`, and apparently tries to convert that string (`"+i+"`)  to a number so that it can use it as an index. And that fails. So what exactly do you want to achieve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is understood as javascript instead of java
With jstl you can iterate a array like this :

```
<c:forEach items="${data}" var="d">
    console.log('${d.name}');
</c:forEach>
```

With scriptlet :

```
<% for(int i=0; i<data.length;i++){%>
    console.log('${data[i].name}');
<% } %>
```

With freemarker : (in .ftl file)

```
<#list data as d>
  console.log('${d.name}');
</#list>
```

Comment: Tried this in the js inside my jsp file. Getting this error SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Comment: the freemarker way works only in freemarker files (.ftl), i edited the post and added other options you have

Comment: Thanks for your help.